# How to catch "Could not make HTTP request" exception when connect with evernote server

Tags: ios, exception, evernote

I'm now developing an app on iOS with evernote api. recently, some problems confuse me, here is the code

```
EDAMAuthenticationResult* authResult = nil;
@try {
    authResult =[userStore authenticate:username :password : consumerKey :consumerSecret];
}    
@catch (EDAMUserException * e) {
    NSString * errorMessage = nil;
    switch ([e errorCode]) {
        case EDAMErrorCode_INVALID_AUTH:
            errorMessage = @"username and password did not match";
            break;
        default:
            errorMessage = @"unknown";
            break;
    }
    [MyAppUtility alertWithTitle:@"Evernote" content:errorMessage];
}
```

I'm now can catch EDAMErrorCode_INVALID_AUTH exception, but when turn wifi off, the app crash with exception "Could not make HTTP request". how to idea with this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to handle [EDAMUserException](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/Errors.html#Struct_EDAMUserException), [EDAMSystemException](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/Errors.html#Struct_EDAMSystemException) and TTransportException. You're probably encountering a TTransportException in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I get the exception information about function [userStore authenticate](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/UserStore.html#Fn_UserStore_authenticate) on [this site](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/), but it show only  exception about Errors.EDAMUserException and Errors.EDAMSystemException, where to get full exception information about each evernote api function?

Comment: Have a look at the headers:
- (EDAMAuthenticationResult *) authenticate: (NSString *) username : (NSString *) password : (NSString *) consumerKey : (NSString *) consumerSecret;  // throws EDAMUserException *, EDAMSystemException *, TException